# Altering ShareThis message with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sharethis

I have a ShareThis widget in my ASP.Net app, on clicking on it a popup is launched and the user can type a message and then share it with a number of services. I want to set a more useful context-relevant 'canned' message, but I cannot get this to work. My code and a screenshot is below.

[image]

```
<div id="ShareDiv"><span class='st_sharethis_large' displayText='ShareThis'></span>
        <span id="button_1" class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
        <span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
        <span class='st_googleplus_large' displayText='Google +'></span>
        <span class='st_email_large' displayText='Email'></span></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> var switchTo5x = true; </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> stLight.options({ publisher: "ur-ae96e1f4-e30b-b79b-fb91-                           54d133283702" }); </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#ShareDiv').click(
                function(){
                    $('textarea').val('Some useful canned message');
                });
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

Just add the parameter st_msg (and st_via if you wish) to your span tag with the class "st_twitter_large".

Answer from: http://support.sharethis.com/customer/portal/articles/517332